# "Strict Standards"-Error after PHP-Update

Tags: php

i need to update my php-version. The site still runs with 5.2. The problem is every newer version results in an error.

Errors at php version 5.3+:

- Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
  /xxx/xxx on line 52
- Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
  /xxx/xxx on line 84
- Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
  /xxx/xxx on line 85

Here are the affected lines:

```
52: $this->pathToModule = realpath ( self::$MODULE_DIRECTORY .     DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . Filter::instance( $tmpStr = $name )->toLowerCase() );
84: $backendClassName   = Filter::instance($tmp = $this->name)->camelize() . self::BACKEND_FILESUFFIX;
85: $frontendClassName  = Filter::instance($tmp = $this->name)->camelize() . self::FRONTEND_FILESUFFIX;
```

Has anyone an idea where the problem could be?

Thank you in advance,

Marvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So set your temps as variables before the Filter call rather than assigning them within the argument:

Change

```
$frontendClassName  = Filter::instance($tmp = $this->name)->camelize() . self::FRONTEND_FILESUFFIX;
```

to

```
$tmp = $this->name;
$frontendClassName  = Filter::instance($tmp)->camelize() . self::FRONTEND_FILESUFFIX;
```

etc

But watch out in case $tmp is modified by the call